# write_canonical() and natural language interpretation

Tags: prolog, declarative

> Implement the following two operators has and of in such a way that
>   with phrases like: peter has car of john answers to questions such as:
>   Who has What of X

I have this simple program that define two operator: **has** (that specify **who have what**) and **of** (that specifies who owns what)

This is the solution write in a Prolog source file:

```
:- op(100, xfy, of).
:- op(200, xfx, has).

peter has car of john.
peter has car of mary.

car of john of mary.
```

As I can read on the official SWI Prolog documentation related to **write_canonical()** function: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=write_canonical%2F1

> Write Term on the current output stream using standard parenthesized
>   prefix notation (i.e., ignoring operator declarations). Atoms that
>   need quotes are quoted.

So if I launch a Prolog query inside write_canonical() function:

```
15 ?- write_canonical(peter has car of john).
has(peter,of(car,john))
true.
```

I obtain how Prolog interprets the natural language form, is it right?

In the previous case it is pretty simple and appear clear that first evaluate the sentence: **(car of john)** and then evaluate the sentence: **peter has (result of previous evaluation)**

having the following interpretation: **peter has (car of john)**

Ok, this is clear...now we come to my question.

If I do:

```
16 ?- write_canonical(peter has car of john of mary).
has(peter,of(car,of(john,mary)))
true.
```

How can I interpret it in natural language? (if that makes any sense in natural language)

At the beginning I I had initially interpreted as the car belongs booth to john and to mary...so I have try to introduce the fact 3 facts of the previous example but if in the Prolog shell I try to execute:

```
10 ?- peter has car of john of mary.
false.
```

This appear false.

What is the correct interpretation in natural language?

Answer (score 1):

I did a double take while reading your previous question about this and CapelliC's answer. It should be actually read,

"Peter has a car, which belongs to John, *who* [John] belongs to Marry."

Your interpretation should have been (using `write_canonical`) something like:

```
has(peter, of(car, [john,marry]))
```

or maybe

```
has(peter, of(car, john)), has(peter, of(car, marry))
```

depending how you want to implement it, but also, if it is actually the same car (which is not completely clear from your example).

"Peter has car of John of Mary" is of course not conventional English.

Comment: mmm ok...but, if I add to my facts list the following facts: john of mary. (that specify that john belongs to mary)...if then I go in the prolog shell and I try to perform the query: peter has car of john of mary. this result FALSE...why? I have that "peter ha car of john" fact and also that "john of mary" facts...why don't it is true?

Comment: I have also try to add these 2 facts in the facts list of my Prolog program: john of mary. and mary of ann. But if I perform the query: john of mary of ann. This result FALSE...it is strange because I have declared my of operator having form xfy...what is wrong? TNX